# What can cause a process to be run in Windows 10's Session 0?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, task-manager

For my project, I have a GUI executable kick off a number of background processes that all communicate with each other to partition data processing. Recently, I copied over the GUI to another machine, and recompiled the background executables to test it.

To my surprise, when I tried to attach to the kickstarted processes in Visual Studio, I couldn't find them in the list of processes, or in the task manager. Eventually, after searching for executables running for any user, I found the processes running under 'session 0', Windows 10's isolation mode, and subsequently needed admin permissions to debug them!

I'd like to run these executables in my user session, and to do that, I need to understand what may have caused them to run in session 0 in the first place. What can prompt an executable to be run at that level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following applications will run in session 0:

- System services that create a UI.
- A system service that tries to use API message functions such as `SendMessage`
  and `PostMessage` to communicate with the user.
- Applications creating global named objects.

If your applications is not running as a system service, or creating such a service,
then it must be creating global named objects.

Global named objects have object names prefixed with "Global\".
These are usually shared-memory segments or semaphores of all kinds.
You may view them using
[WinObj](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj)
in the "GLOBAL??" section.